# HTML img src returning a 404 not found error despite everything in order

Tags: html, image, http-status-code-404, src

here's a confusing thing. first look at the [hierarchy of my folders and etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5U8a.png) and see that I have my image, "cribbage.png" under the images folder. I am trying to access this image with the following code in index.html:`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World! </h1>
        <img src= "images/cribbage.png" width= "970" height="224"/>
        <div id = "future"></div>
        <form id = "form" id = "chat_form">
            <input id = "username" type="text">
            <input type = "submit" value="Play">
        </form>
        <script src = "/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js">
    </body>
</html>
```

and yet, when loading the website I get
[the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10nC6.png) and the image is replaced with the broken image icon.

What exactly is wrong here?

Comment: your url points to `localhost/images/yourimagename.jpg` whereas your folder structure is `localhost/crib/images/yourimagename.jpg`

Answer (score 3):

I have noticed that some web frameworks don't allow you to have your images or videos anywhere you want. For example, while looking for the solution for this problem, I remembered that Flask (the framework I was using) does not render any images or videos that are not in the "static" folder.

I don't know if other frameworks have something like this, but if you think you have everything in order, you should take this into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

The images field is not on the same folder as index.html. Meaning your path should get out of the node_modules folder and then get in the images folder.

you should use / (to get out of the node folder) images and then/ (to get in the images folder )cribbage.png

so ../images/cribbage.png

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, however I'm still mysteriously getting the same 404 error.

Comment: Try <img src="../images/cribbage.png">

Answer (score 1):

check on the folder that the name of the image is in lowercase because it is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<img src= "/images/cribbage.png" width= "970" height="224"/>
```

Comment: This does not work, same 404 error and image is still not found.

Comment: in your "hierarchy of my folders and etc" link are you trying to get the image on the "index.html" file located in the "/node_modules" folder ? if so do  ../images/cribbage.png

Comment: if this is the case and it fixes your issue i'd suggest moving the imgages folder inside the /node_modules folder and the code that i first gave you :)

Comment: this was not in fact the case, and the problem persists. I tried doing ../images/cribbage.png anyway and it still did not work.

Comment: where is the html file you're trying to load the image on?

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: so if your index.html is inside the node_nodules folder and you also have your webserver pointing to that location you can't jump out of that folder. meaning your website will only see that directory. if you want any images you must put it inside the same directory or use a url.   so put the images folder inside the folder where the index.html is

Answer (score 0):

Is the images folder in the right place?
Make sure you can access to the folder from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<img src="../../../Images/Gallery/error2.jpg"  width= "500" height="300" CssStyle="text-align:center"/>
</div>
</form>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Add commens that will explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had too many folders **e.i img/images**, so I moved all my images from **images** folder to **img** folder, and all my images show successfully

Answer (score 0):

you should try this
 `<img src= "./images/cribbage.png" width= "970" height="224"/>`

Answer (score -1):

put the full URL link.
eg: your server name test.com
http://test.com/imagefoldername/imagename

Comment: this is an old question.  I don't believe that your short answer actually answers the question as is, and definitely not more than any other existing answer.